# The notion of morphisms between two moduli problems in Katz-Mazur

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading Katz-Mazur Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves, and have some questions about the notion of morphisms between two moduli problems.

> 1. What is the proper definition of morphisms between two moduli problems ?

A moduli problem $\mathcal{P}$ is a contravariant functor $(\mathcal{E}ll)\to (Sets)$, so I think that a morphism between two moduli problems $\mathcal{P}_1,\mathcal{P}_2$ should be a natural transformation, that is, for any elliptic curve $E/S$, there is a map $\mathcal{P}_1(E/S)\to\mathcal{P}_2(E/S)$ which sits into the commutative diagrams concerning morphisms in $(\mathcal{E}ll)$.

Besides, I think there may be some other conditions should be satisfied, since there are statements like "$\mathcal{P}_1$ is relatively representable over $\mathcal{P}_2$", "$\mathcal{P}_1$ is finite flat over $\mathcal{P}_2$" and so on. And the questions:

> 2. What is the meaning of "$\mathcal{P}_1$ is relatively representable over $\mathcal{P}_2$" ?

> 3. Let P be a property of morphisms of schemes, what is the definition of "a morphism between two moduli problems has property P"?

Maybe there is some natural map between the $S$-schemes $\mathcal{P}_{1,E/S}\to\mathcal{P}_{2,E/S}$ when we say a morphism between $\mathcal{P}_1$,$\mathcal{P}_2$, and the answer of question 3 is that if these morphisms have Property P ? (or just for some certain elliptic curves $E/S$).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

1. That's correct. We would like this to give a morphism between the underlying stacks, i.e. the functor that takes $S$ to the groupoid of pairs of an elliptic curve $E/S$ and an element of $\mathcal P_i(E)$ up to isomorphism. Morphisms between stacks are given by natural transformations of functors and a natural transformation $\mathcal P_1(E) \to \mathcal P_2(E)$ of sets certainly gives a natural transformation of pairs.
2. It should be the same as the notion of a representable morphism of stacks. That is $\mathcal P_1$ is relatively representable if, for each elliptic curve $E/S$ and $p \in \mathcal P_2(E)$, there is a scheme $T/S$ such that the functors sending $U/S$ to, on the one hand, morphisms $U \to T$ over $S$, and, on the other hand, $q \in \mathcal P_1 (E \times_S U)$ that are sent to $p$ under $\mathcal P_1\to \mathcal P_2$, are naturally isomorphic.
3. Usually this means that $\mathcal P_1$ is relatively representable and, for all $E/S$ and $p\in \mathcal P_2(E)$,  $T\to S$ has property $P$.